# Can Zathura's "dual" page mode use a page offset?

Tags: pdf, zathura

When viewing PDFs that are setup for print, I often want to view facing page spreads. Typically PDFs are typeset such that the first page of the file/part/chapter always starts on a right page so facing page spreads are always even-odd number pairs. Unfortunately Zathura's "dual" display mode shows everything in odd-even pairs starting with 1-2.

Is there some way to setup display of facing-pages much the way most PDF readers default to in 2-up modes?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes this is possible, it's just not well documented. Or [documented at all](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/documentation/) for that matter. The only reference I found was in [an issue report](http://bugs.pwmt.org/issue402).

- Once a file is opened, you can change the first page location by running `:set first-page-column 2` from the command line.
- This same line can be added to the rc file at `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc` to make it the default.

**Note:** Since zathura 0.3.5 the format for this setting has changed. It is no longer a fixed value for all page configuration but can be set independently for different numbers of columns. As a result in order to set this for a two column layout you actually need to set the second column of the setting, the above format will have no effect. The new format looks like this:

```
:set first-page-column 1:2
```

Or if you want to set layouts for 3 and 4 column views as well:

```
:set first-page-column 1:2:1:2
```

That will start three column views with the first column but use skip to the second column to start 2 and 4 page spreads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as it helped me with this particular adjustment.  Later on, I realized that `zathura` settings is actually well documented in `man` pages which can be invoked at a Linux command line using:  `man zathura` and `man zathurarc`.  Moreover, by typing `:set` and hitting `tab` a list of all settings parameters along with a brief description for each appears.

Comment: @Pooya I believe both tab completion and the config man page post-date this answer, but yes those are good resources to point people towards!